# Wordpress thumbnail image only shows in category page

Tags: php, wordpress, image, thumbnails

For some reason, I cannot add a thumbnail through the 'Featured Image' option. If you take a look at [this site](http://pinboard.comuf.com/Wordpress/), you'll see that there are no images in the first three posts. My theme does support thumbnails and I have added a featured image on those three posts, but it's just not showing up. However, if you click on 'Movies', you'll see that the images suddenly appear.

**EDIT:** I believe what's causing the problem is this piece of code, the 'if condition'

```
     <?php if ( is_archive() || is_search() ) : // Only display Excerpts for archives & search ?>
<div class="entry-summary">
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() && !post_password_required() ) { ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" class="thumb"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'portfolio-thumbnail-fullwidth' ); ?></a>

    <?php } ?>
    <?php the_excerpt( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'portfoliopress' ) ); ?>
  </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
   <?php else : ?>
    <div class="entry-content">
    <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'portfoliopress' ) ); ?>
    <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'portfoliopress' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
   </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    <?php endif; ?>
```

**EDIT2:** Just confirmed that it is indeed the if condition that is causing the differences. But I have no idea how to remove it, neither if it will affect the content (besides the images?)

**Edit3:** So sorry, I fixed it myself. I probably wouldn't have solved it if I hadn't posted it though.

Comment: Do you use `post-formats` and have different **content-*.php** templates?

Comment: Yes I do, the theme supports 4 formats + 1 special. But I tried using featured images for all 5. Same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why the theme creators did this. But anyway, anyone else using Portfolio Press and would like to have thumbnails in their posts, remove the if condition and remove one of the entry divs.